# How to unit test aop(aspect class)

Tags: junit, aop, aspectj

How to unit test the following method using JUnit4??

```
public Object invoke(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Object serviceObject = null;
    BaseServiceRequest baseServiceRequest = null;
    ServiceContext serviceContext = null;

    baseServiceRequest = (BaseServiceRequest) joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
    if (baseServiceRequest == null)
        ExceptionHandlerUtil.createExceptionType("SL","BaseServiceRequest cannot be empty", new Object[] {});

    serviceContext = baseServiceRequest.getServiceContext();
    ExceptionHandlerUtil.createExceptionType("SL","ServiceContext cannot be empty", new Object[] {});
    createServiceInvocationInterceptor(baseServiceRequ est,joinPoint);

    serviceObject = getServiceObject(serviceContext, joinPoint);
    serviceContext.getMethodInvocationEvent().setReturnValue(serviceObject);

    return serviceObject;
}
```

Comment: Declaring your variables at the top like that makes things more difficult to read. How come you don't check `serviceContext` for `null`?

Comment: Actually we are declaring serviceContext, The value will come from baseServiceRequest.getServiceContext(); using joinPoint

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is what you want to know because the question is kind of unclear, but if you want to know how to mock objects used by a production aspect for unit testing, you can use another aspect - let's call it a meta aspect or testing aspect - in order to do that. I have described a way to do it under [How to mock an aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825325/how-to-mock-an-aspect/11906391#11906391).